# Conditional on input in angular that gets a calculated value from other inputs

Tags: angular

Okay so I have an input that is read only that gets it's value from other inputs, then I am trying to run a conditional to show or hide based on that input value being populated.

```
<input id="incomeOutput" readonly="readonly "name="incomeOutput"   
   [(ngModel)]="incomeOutput"  [value]="[monthly_pension.value*12 + 
    monthly_investments.value*12 + monthly_annuities.value*12 +  
    monthly_SSI.value*12]" >
```

Then I am conditionally checking like so

```
[hidden]="(this.stepTwo.classList.value === 'step active' && (this.incomeOutput === 0))"
```

I have `incomeOuput` set to a number.

But when I console `incomeOutput` it comes out undefined and I never see the change made during the conditional. Conditionals work fine in all instances except this.

Answer (score 0):

you can not use [(ngModel)] -two binding way- with [value] to give value to one variable.

You can use a [template reference variable](https://angular.io/guide/template-reference-variables) (but a template reference variable, in the .html give you access to the htmlInput, so you can use incomeOutput.value -see in this case that the "value" is a string-).

```html
    <!--the #incomeOutput, indicate that is a template reference variable-->
    <!--see also that not use [ ]-->
    <!--and you need use a "+" to convert to "number", 
        in general the [(ngModel)] give us a "string"
        -->
    <input #incomeOutput" readonly="readonly "name="incomeOutput" 
           [ngModel]="+monthly_pension.value12 + (+monthly_investments.value12) 
                      + (+monthly_annuities.value12) + (+monthly_SSI.value12)" >
    
    <!--see how access to "value" of the htmlElement and the "+" before
        to convert To Number-->
    <div [hidden]="(this.stepTwo.classList.value === 'step active' && 
           +incomeOutput.value==0>
```

a [fool stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-3uig14?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html)

Comment: Thanks for the + I missed that. I wasn't sure why sometimes the calculated number was concatenating. I am still not able to get the value though.

Comment: @KujoCode, I add a fool stackblitz, Check if you has a variable called equal than the template reference variable

Comment: That is great, I really appreciate that "Fool stackblitz" works fine as long as I am keeping the button inside the container along with the template variable but I am not. The buttons are in a "footer" component and that is throwing "not in AppComponent". I am assuming I need to access the variable in the component class.

Comment: if the "footerComponent" is in the same "<router-outlet>" you can pass as `@Input` the htmlElement (I updated the stackblitz) else you need communicate between components using a service, see the [docs](https://angular.io/guide/component-interaction#parent-and-children-communicate-using-a-service)

Comment: it's because it is set behind an ngIf so I can either set it to hidden or run it through a directive.